# Techno dilemma for a secure and 'app compatible' web architecture

Tags: security, architecture

I want to develop a simple website that will have simple features: user management, online payment and some simple data management. On top, I want to develop an iPhone app that will interact with the users's data. And in a close future, I would develop an Androïd app.

Now I need to develop this application in a *very* secure way, from user authentication to data security.

I know a little of web frameworks like Symfony 1 and Django. And I'm a good Java programmer.

What would be your choice of technology to achieve my to goals of security and easy iApp interaction?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would learn Symfony 2. They took great efforts to improve the security for 2, including getting a security assessment for the core framework and doctrine. There are a lot of changes from sf1.x, but the jump isn't too bad (i just did it myself).

Symfony is a good base for a new project, but it wont make everything you do secure. That is far beyond the scope of a post on stackoverflow. My best advice: read some of the articles on http://owasp.org, maybe watch a few presentations on specific subjects you are worried about, and keep an eye on security blogs/mailing lists.

Comment: Oh and i forgot to mention - symfony2 uses a template engine designed to be identical to django.